# Odoo 9: Unable to use math functions in Salary Rule

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-9

First of all, I'm a Python beginner and learning to use Odoo now. I have been trying roundup the result using Python Code in Salary Rule.

Payroll\Configuration\Salary Rules

I found out there is a math function of math.ceil() to roundup the result. So I code the code below:

```
import math
result = math.ceil(categories.BASIC * 0.05)
```

But I couldn't get it to work. Did I import the math library correctly?

Comment: "... couldn't get it to work."  Is there an error somewhere?  If `categories.BASIC` is a number then the code should work. (admittedly not familiar with odoo-9)

Comment: yes `categories.BASIC` is a number. The error shown in odoo is _Wrong python code defined for salary rule RULE NAME._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't import python modules there, an alternative is to use the built-in [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) function in python

```
result = round((categories.BASIC * 0.05) + 0.5)
```

Here I just specified to round the result to 2 digits, but it can be anything you want

Comment: Actually I have tried that already. It does not output the result I need. I wish to roundup the number regardless of how many cents. For example, 20.01, 20.30, 20.50 and so on will roundup to 21.00.

Comment: you can add `0.5` to the answer to mimic `math.ceil` (It's hacky but it works)

Comment: Sorry, didn't see the `+0.5` earlier. Yes. I just tested the code out and it works as expected. thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
#round by 100 
arl = contract.arl_wage_rate/100

base = (worked_days.TRAB100.amount+worked_days.AUSLEG.amount)*arl)

residual = (base/100) - round(base/100)

if residual > 0:
    residual = 1

else:
    residual = 0

result = (round(base/100) + residual) * 100
```

Comment: Does this answer the question? Maybe you could add a few words explaining your code sample and why you think it is an answer to the question.